# Finding index of giving conditions and specified index set

Tags: matlab

Given a vector `x` belongs to `R^n`, an index subset `I` of `S=(1, ..., n)`, I want to find the index of the largest elements of `x` in `I, or the index in the full vector.

In other words, how do I find the index of the largest element of a sub vector in the original vector's index space?

What's the best way to do this in MATLAB?

Currently, I use:

```
xmax = max(x(I));
i = I(x(I) == xmax);
i = i(1);
```

I'm looking for a more efficient way to achieve this.

## Example:

```
x = [4, 2, 4];
S = [1, 2, 3];
I = [2, 3];
```

The desired output would be 3.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `x` is an n-dimensional array (matrix). `I` has *linear* indices. If so, then `xmax = max(x(I));` should suffice. Using `find` will get you the index (and not the element itself). If this is not the case, then your notations are not clear to me.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Hello, I'm sorry I've made a mistake in the question. I'll correct it now. It seems that ```xmax=max(x(I))``` will return the index of the max element in the subvector. For the example, this will return ```2```.

Comment: @displayname - No.  That will return the maximum value that is found within the array that is used as input into `max`.  Therefore, what would actually be returned is **4**.  If you want the **index** of the maximum value, you need to use the **two-output** version of `max`, so `[xmax,loc] = max(x(I));`.  Either way, I've written an answer.

Comment: @displayname - BTW, declaring `S` is superfluous.  If we know for a fact that `I` will always be bounded between 1 to `numel(x)`, then the declaration of `S` is not required.  In fact, you don't use this in your example.

Comment: @rayryeng I know that ```S``` is not needed and just want to explain well. But it seems that I still messed it because of my broken English... Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the two output version of `max`.  The second output will give you the **location** of where the maximum element was found.  However, if there are multiple entries where the maximum was found, it will only find the **first occurrence**.  You can then use the second output of `max` to index into `I` to get what you want.  Therefore:

```
[~,loc] = max(x(I));
i = I(loc);
```

Comment: ```You can then use the second output of max to index into I to get what you want. ``` Thanks for your information about this.